# DotNetOpenAuth OpenID Provider "Sequence contains more than one element"

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth, openid-provider

I'm having trouble implementing my OpenID provider with DNOA 3.4.3. Everything was going absolutely peachy until I needed AX support as well. I set AXFetchAsSregTransform in the web config, as recommended by Andrew at http://groups.google.com/group/dotnetopenid/browse_thread/thread/5629a24c0a7e8d99. Doing this caused me to get the exception "Sequence Contains More Than One Element" on my decide.aspx page, however, and I haven't been able to get past it.

The following line is throwing the exception:
***Edit:** Strangely enough, this is not the line throwing the error anymore. The SendResponse() is now triggering the exception*

<strike>ClaimsRequest requestedFields = ProviderEndpoint.PendingRequest.GetExtension();</strike>

```
ProviderEndpoint.SendResponse()
```

Any thoughts on why this may be? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The logs leading up to the error are as follows:

> ```
> 2010-04-28 12:38:20,247 (GMT-7) [5] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Scanning incoming request for messages: https://myprovider/provider.ashx?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.email=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.type.fullname=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson&openid.ext1.type.language=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fpref%2Flanguage&openid.ext1.required=email&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmyrelyingparty%2Flogin.jsp%3Foidreturn%3D%252Fhome&openid.assoc_handle=%7B634080802953194640%7D%7BHxjFNw==%7D%7B20%7D&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fmyrelyingparty
> 2010-04-28 12:38:20,285 (GMT-7) [5] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Processing incoming CheckIdRequest (2.0) message:
>     openid.claimed_id: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
>     openid.identity: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
>     openid.assoc_handle: {634080802953194640}{HxjFNw==}{20}
>     openid.return_to: http://myrelyingparty/login.jsp?oidreturn=%2Fhome
>     openid.realm: http://myrelyingparty/
>     openid.mode: checkid_setup
>     openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
>     openid.ns.ext1: http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
>     openid.ext1.mode: fetch_request
>     openid.ext1.type.email: http://axschema.org/contact/email
>     openid.ext1.type.fullname: http://axschema.org/namePerson
>     openid.ext1.type.language: http://axschema.org/pref/language
>     openid.ext1.required: email
>
> 2010-04-28 12:38:22,773 (GMT-7) [14] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Scanning incoming request for messages: https://myprovider/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdecide.aspx
> 2010-04-28 12:38:36,167 (GMT-7) [5] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Scanning incoming request for messages: https://myprovider/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdecide.aspx
> 2010-04-28 12:38:38,147 (GMT-7) [14] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging - Protocol error: An HTTP request to the realm URL (http://myrelyingparty/) resulted in a redirect, which is not allowed during relying party discovery.
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.VerifyProtocol(Boolean condition, String message, Object[] args)
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Realm.Discover(IDirectWebRequestHandler requestHandler, Boolean allowRedirects)
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Realm.DiscoverReturnToEndpoints(IDirectWebRequestHandler requestHandler, Boolean allowRedirects)
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider.HostProcessedRequest.IsReturnUrlDiscoverableCore(OpenIdProvider provider)
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider.HostProcessedRequest.IsReturnUrlDiscoverable(OpenIdProvider provider)
>    at OpenIdProviderWebForms.decide.Page_Load(Object src, EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>    at ASP.decide_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
>    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
>    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>
> 2010-04-28 12:38:38,149 (GMT-7) [14] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Relying party discovery at URL http://myrelyingparty/ failed.  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: An HTTP request to the realm URL (http://myrelyingparty/) resulted in a redirect, which is not allowed during relying party discovery.
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.VerifyProtocol(Boolean condition, String message, Object[] args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bf9e2ca68b75a334\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\ErrorUtilities.cs:line 235
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Realm.Discover(IDirectWebRequestHandler requestHandler, Boolean allowRedirects) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bf9e2ca68b75a334\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OpenId\Realm.cs:line 446
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Realm.DiscoverReturnToEndpoints(IDirectWebRequestHandler requestHandler, Boolean allowRedirects) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bf9e2ca68b75a334\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OpenId\Realm.cs:line 424
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider.HostProcessedRequest.IsReturnUrlDiscoverableCore(OpenIdProvider provider) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bf9e2ca68b75a334\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OpenId\Provider\HostProcessedRequest.cs:line 142
> 2010-04-28 12:38:42,076 (GMT-7) [8] ERROR OpenIdProviderWebForms.Global - An unhandled exception was raised. Details follow: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider.Request.GetExtension[T]() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bf9e2ca68b75a334\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OpenId\Provider\Request.cs:line 176
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.ExtensionsInteropHelper.ConvertSregToMatchRequest(IHostProcessedRequest request) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bf9e2ca68b75a334\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OpenId\Extensions\ExtensionsInteropHelper.cs:line 180
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform.DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider.IProviderBehavior.OnOutgoingResponse(IAuthenticationRequest request) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bf9e2ca68b75a334\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OpenId\Behaviors\AXFetchAsSregTransform.cs:line 139
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider.OpenIdProvider.ApplyBehaviorsToResponse(IRequest request) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bf9e2ca68b75a334\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OpenId\Provider\OpenIdProvider.cs:line 482
>    at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider.OpenIdProvider.SendResponse(IRequest request) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\bf9e2ca68b75a334\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OpenId\Provider\OpenIdProvider.cs:line 325
>    at OpenIdProviderWebForms.decide.Yes_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\OpenIdProviderWebForms\decide.aspx.cs:line 130
>    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>    at ASP.decide_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7f580b93\b3e4d917\App_Web_tulh9ymv.1.cs:line 0
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
> ```

Comment: Can you please include the logs of the request leading up to the error?

Comment: Update: I tested against test-id.org (I found it in another one of Andrew's posts.. what a gem!), and it returns the same "More than one sequence" error. In addition, I'm having trouble with my relying party implementation of the behavior as well. Just posted it on Google Groups, I'll add a link as soon as the post is approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops.  You found a bug in DotNetOpenAuth.

Fix checked into [v3.2 as 7cea654](http://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/commits/7cea654) and [v3.4 as bd7c148](http://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/commits/bd7c148).  You can get the fix in [tomorrow's build](http://teamcity.dotnetopenauth.net:82/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt49&tab=buildTypeStatusDiv).

Comment: Right on! Thanks for getting this taken care of, mate.